# Overload error for method "System.Net.CredentialCache.Add" in PSCore 6.2.3

Tags: .net, powershell, methods, credentials, networkcredentials

I have the following script to perform an availability check for a password-protected localhost site:

```
Function CheckAvailability ($Url, $Credentials)
{
    $WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
    [System.Net.CredentialCache]$CredentialCache = New-Object System.Net.CredentialCache
    $CredentialCache.Add($Url, "Basic", $Credentials)
    $WebClient.Credentials = $CredentialCache

    If ($WebClient.DownloadString($Url))
    {
        Return $True
    }
    Else
    {
        Return $False
    }
}

Function Main ()
{
    $Url = "http://localhost/resource"
    $Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("admin","password","") #UserName, Password, Domain
    CheckAvailability($Url, $Credentials)
}

Main
```

If I run the script, I get the following error

> Cannot find an overload for "Add" and the argument count: "3". At
>   D:\WebSiteTest.ps1
>   +     $CredentialCache.Add($Url, "Basic", $Credentials)
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest

I've read that the method `add` and it should support 3 or 4 parameters (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.credentialcache.add?view=netframework-4.8). Can someone tell me, what the issue is here? I am running Powershell Core 6.2.3.

I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: The documentation you're following is for .net framework 4.8 check if you have that framework installed. Powershell version is not directly related to .net version

Comment: But it's the same for 3.5, for instance: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.credentialcache.add?view=netframework-3.5 I have .net framework 3.5 and 4.8

Comment: It looks like the Add function definitively wants the first parameter to be of type `Uri`, but you are sending it a String. Try `$CredentialCache.Add([Uri]$Url, "Basic", $Credentials)`